# when i clicked on button the border color change default in black color in html and css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I used a two-button when I clicked on that button div should be changed using javascript replaced the function the problem is when I click on the button border should be changed by default black color I could not find where it was added that I'm adding screenshots. it happened after I added on click replaced function [image: when I clicked on that border color is black]

```js
<script>
        function replace(hide, show) {
            document.getElementById(hide).style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById(show).style.display = "block";
        }
    </script>
```

```html
     <div class="two_btn">
            <div class="order_btn">
                <button type="button"  onclick="replace('div2','div1')">Order & Collect</button>
            </div>
            <div class="book_collection">
                <button type="button" onclick="replace('div1','div2')">Book UK Collection</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: try button{outline:none}

Comment: @Minal Chauhan not working

Comment: Please add css code...

Comment: @Minal Chauhan, it's done. I'm adding in this style i inline styling now it's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an on-focus outline, automatically added by your browser. To remove it completely (not advisable), you can add this to your CSS:

```css
button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

Why you should not do this and use a different approach instead:

https://www.a11yproject.com/posts/never-remove-css-outlines/

http://www.outlinenone.com/